# Standard language or model theory for Complex Event Processing system

Tags: standards, complex-event-processing

We are developing a library for complex event processing. 
Is there any standard or widely accepted language with clear semantics that we could based on?
After some research it seems all available options are vendor/platform specific.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is no common CEP language now, Most of the venders are either using a SQL like language or a UI based tool.

SQL like language seems to be the more feasible approach due to easy of development of a CEP engine, 
We have tried to come up with a [SQL like language](http://docs.wso2.org/display/CEP300/Siddhi+Language+Specification) for a Java based CEP engine. 
This might be helpful for you.

Suho